# appendTo doesn't take my ID

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, clone, addition

I am not so good at JS, but I am trying to add dynamically a row with content (clone). This is working, IF I put

```
        var apcount = 0;

        function add(id, apmax) {
        var aptable = id;
            if (apmax > apcount) {
                $("table tr:last").clone().appendTo("#m1s1t2").find(':input').attr('name', function(index, name) {
                    return name.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(fullMatch, n) {
                        return Number(n) + 1;
                    });
                })
            }; apcount++;
        }
```

the 'id' direct into '.appendTo'. The call of this function is a button

```
<input onclick="add('m1s1t2',2)" type="button">
```

Actually I want to have something like '.appendTo(id)'

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use the id variable you pass in

change

```
.appendTo("#m1s1t2")
```

to

```
.appendTo("#" + id)
```

Comment: OMG! THANKS! Tried everything with '', "", but had no idea of "#" + id. Great job.